# pass object reference into javascript async function, but the unexpected value gotten

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I use the object as the function parameter to try saving out the value of the consequence of a async function. Code snippets shown bellow,

```
function sleep(ms) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));}
...

let u={};
async function exec(){
     getCurrUser(action.w,u);//get current user login data from indexeddb io
     await sleep(2000);
};
exec().then(()=>{console.log(u); /*u is still {}, but WHY ?*/ });   });
```

getCurrentUser is something like

```
export function getCurrUser(window,user) {
   ...
 _req.onsuccess=function(event){
                let cursor=event.target.result;
                //confirm in this line that user object does has some value
                if(cursor) {user = Object.assign({}, cursor);return;}
                else {return;}
            };
  ...

}
```

My understanding is that if the timeout is long enough to secure the valid execution of getCurrUser, I can get the final function output through the 2nd paramter reference. But the fact is not so. Why? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Btw it's more appropriate to change getCurrUser into an async function, or to return a promise, than it is to wait 2 seconds. I see that TJCrowder did something like that in his response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign to `user` in the callback in `getCurrUser`, all you're doing is assigning to the parameter (making it refer to a newly-created object); that parameter has **no link whatsoever** to the `u` variable you passed into `getCurrUser`.

When you do:

```
getCurrUser(action.w,u);
```

...you're reading the current *value* of `u` and passing that value into `getCurrUser` as `user`. Assigning a *new* value to `user` has no effect on `u` at all. The value, not the variable, was passed.

While you could solve this in *this specific case* by doing [what TKoL shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48765595/157247), I would make `getCurrUser` return a promise instead, and consume the promise rather than relying on writing to pre-created objects, making `exec` close over `u`, etc.:

```
function sleep(ms) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));}

async function exec(){
     const u = await getCurrUser(action.w); //get current user login data from indexeddb io
     await sleep(2000);
     return u;
};

exec()
    .then(u => {
        console.log(u);
    })
    .catch(e => {
        // deal with the error -- you MUST always either handle
        // rejections or return the promise chain to something that will
    });

export function getCurrUser(window) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // ...
        _req.onsuccess = function(event) {
            let cursor = event.target.result;
            //confirm in this line that user object does has some value
            if (cursor) {
                 resolve(Object.assign({}, cursor);
            } else {
                 reject(new Error(/*...*/));
            }
        };
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `user = Object.assign({}, cursor);`, you are NOT changing the 'u' variable, you are reassigning the 'user' variable.

Try `Object.assign(user, cursor)` -- this should modify the <s>u variable</s> object `u` refers to.

Comment: But yes, in this specific situation, if `getCurrUser` is supposed to fill in the object, that solution will do so. I'd argue the functions need a rewrite, but yes, this would work.

Comment: Yes, sure, 'modify the object u refers to' is what I meant colloquially by 'modify the u variable'. That's a more accurate way to phrase it.

Answer (score 1):

`user = Object...` overwrites the *value of the `user` variable*.

This throws away the reference to the object that is created here — `let u={};` — and later assigned to `user`.

The `u` variable continues to point to the *original* object.

You would need to *modify the existing object* and not overwrite the value of `user` with a new one in order to achieve what you want with your current approach.